# How to get DevExpress GridControl to show captions instead of field names?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress, master-detail, gridcontrol

I have a DevExpress GridControl with a master and and detail.  On the detail, I want to show one column.  The dataset I'm using has two columns, the one I want to show and the foreign key back to the master.  In the designer, I've included only the column I want and in design mode it show one column.  However, when I run the application I see both columns with the names from the data set.  How do I get the detail grid to just show the one column I want?

[image]

Here's an example of my code.  I've tried it with and without the level tree add and tried different names for the relation.  Nothing I've tried uses the formatting I set in the designer for the detail view.

```
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim da2 As SqlDataAdapter

        cmd = MSSQL_CONN.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from vw_backlog with (nolock) where order_id = " & m_order.id
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        cmd = MSSQL_CONN.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT order_id, backlog_id, special_handling_id, comment_id, message FROM vw_backlog_special_handling_comments with (nolock) WHERE order_id = " & m_order.id
        da2 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "Backlogs")
        da2.Fill(ds, "Messages")

        Dim keyColumn As DataColumn = ds.Tables("Backlogs").Columns("backlog_id")
        Dim foreignKeyColumn As DataColumn = ds.Tables("Messages").Columns("backlog_id")
        ds.Relations.Add("gvSpecialHandlingComments", keyColumn, foreignKeyColumn)

        gcBacklog.DataSource = ds.Tables("Backlogs")
        gcBacklog.ForceInitialize()

        gcBacklog.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("SpecialHandlingComments", gvSpecialHandlingComments)
        gvSpecialHandlingComments.PopulateColumns(ds.Tables("Messages"))
```

Comment: Was the detail view created automatically or did you create it yourself? What is the data source for your grid control? Is the GridControl's [LevelTree](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.LevelTree.property) property set? It appears your grid control is simply creating a clone view at runtime and ignoring the pattern view you created in the designer. See also: [Patterns & clones](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3473/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Master-Detail-Relationships#patterns-and-clones)

Comment: I've suspected that the control in the designer (gvSpecialingHandlingComments) is either not the one I'm populating in the code.  I'm using the example at https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/732/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/master-detail/working-with-master-detail-relationships-in-code.  How do I populate it using the method in this example and still use the formatting I've set in the designer?

Comment: You can set one of the GridControl's LevelTree nodes to the detail view.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The LevelTree documentation I posted above details how to do that in code at runtime.